# Scrolling content within an overflow:hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have 5 `.kids` in my `#parent` and I want to be able to scroll in between those but only show one at a time. How do I scroll to a different place within my parent div to see a different kid?

#### My CSS:

```
#parent { 
    width:500px; 
    height:600px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}

.kids {     
    display: inline-block; 
    width:500px; 
    height:600px;    
}
```

Sorry for the somewhat LQ question but I'm just stumped.

Comment: You would need JS if you want only one to be visible at a time.

Comment: I'm going to be doing that later, but for now I just want to figure out how I'm going to display one at a time and then go to the next with CSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution using the [**ScrollTo() jQuery plugin**](http://balupton.github.io/jquery-scrollto/).

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/B4ppp/)... and another [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/B4ppp/1/) using `overflow:hidden`, ***(scrollbar hidden)***.

*(click the parent element to scroll in the example...)*

Obviously something similar could have been created without the plugin, but if you wanted the actual scroll feature, I thought it would be easiest just to use it.

**jQuery**

```
var clicks = 300;
$('#parent').click(function(){
    $('#parent').scrollTo(clicks);
    clicks += 300;
    if(clicks>1200){
        clicks=0;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child" id="c1">1</div>
    <div class="child" id="c2">2</div>
    <div class="child" id="c3">3</div>
    <div class="child" id="c4">4</div>
    <div class="child" id="c5">5</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent { 
    width:200px; 
    height:300px; 
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    background:yellow;
}
#parent:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}

.child {     
    width:200px; 
    height:300px;
    font-size:100px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:300px;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: I only want one to be view able at a time.

Comment: @George Want me to write a JS solution?

Comment: I guess and maybe I can pick up on something from it, thanks Josh.

Comment: @George Alright, wrote some JS. See the solution above.. also retagged your question to include JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this easily using `.animate` function!!
You can change the top of the child div

check the live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/Bz6pC/1/)

```
$("#Container").live("click",function(){

       if($("#Container div").position().top<-300)
    $("#Container div").animate({"top":"+=100px"});
    else{
        $("#Container div").animate({"top":"-=100px"});
    }
});
```

The if else condition is not fully done anyway you can get an idea of how to do it and you can change the conditions!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display: inline-block;` from kids' class and it should work and set the overflow to `overflow: scroll;`